# Awkward Behavior of ComboBox by Tab Button in Metro Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, metroframework

**Problem**: My problem is that when my entry form loads, all the combo boxes work fine but when I click the TAB key to jump from one control to another, e.g. moving control from 'Name' text box to 'Father Name' text box, then my combo boxes show all the items in blue color like they are all selected but they actually are not selected.

Combo boxes work fine but seems awkward and it only happens whenever the TAB key is pressed.

**Required solution**: I want a solution for how to get rid of it. I mean that my TAB key does not affect the combo box.

I'm using the Metro framework ([MetroModernUI 1.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/)) and .NET Framework 4.8 in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. Have you ever manage to solve this TAB affects combo boxes color and make them blue like selected?

Comment: What .NET Framework version and what Metro Framework version are you using? I couldn't reproduce this problem with latest version.

Comment: In general, you can override OnDrawItem method or handle DrawItem event and apply your custom paint logic. It should be easy to fix.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.8 and MetroModernUI 1.4.0 (latest).
I didn't quite understood what to do with drawItem. It is ComboBox dram method and it should be applied to each ComboBox and I have lot of them so it's not good solution to me.
Here's what I've figured out. When my ComboBoxes becomes highlighted/selected (blue) after pressing TAB key, ALT key revertes that behaviour. I just need to press ALT key and reopen ComboBox and it's normal again.
But how to make it permanent so this doesn't happen.... ??

Comment: *'I didn't quite understood what to do with `DrawItem`'* → If you want to handle the [`DrawItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event, you can have a single event handler for all the combo boxes; it's pretty easy and straightforward. You can also drive from the `MetroComboBox` and override [`OnDrawitem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.ondrawitem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then use your derived control.

Comment: [MetroModernUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) is a different package from [MetroFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroFramework/).

Comment: Alright, I can confirm the issue as I could reproduce it using MetroModernUI.

Comment: I'm using MetroModernUI framework. It should be the same problem as for MetroFramework this thread started for. I figured out that we can revert this behavior by pressing ALT key and ComboBoxes becomes normal again. Maybe this can help someone to figure out what could be the problem here and how to solve it....

Answer (score 0):

if you want TAB key does not affect the combo box ,use this :

```
metroComboBox1.TabStop = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Navcore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131016/navcore)

Override the ProcessCmdKey method to detect tab press in the form and emulate alt key press programatically.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
   {
      SendKeys.Send("%");
   }
return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```